# Fill Numpy Array by Indexing a 3-element tuple

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working with a list of tuples and need to index the first 2 elements (out of 3) of the tuple to get the 3rd value.  After that (or while I do that), I also need to create a numpy array to extract those values according to their index (the index should mirror the index of the tuple).

Thus far, I've created a list of lists in order to pull out the 3rd element from the tuple and there's empty lists where there's no value from the tuple.  My question is..is there a way to fill these empty lists with 0's so that when I flatten the list, the empty lists don't disappear and mess with the indexing?  Or is there a different way? Another option I tried was to edit the list comprehension directly to see if I can get a 0 value output when the i,j index didn't exist in the list of tuples, but that didn't work either.  If there's a better way to do this than how I'm currently tackling it, please let me know.

Indirect Output Needed (output of for-loop):

```
lst2=[28,2,1,4,8,5,1,4,3,3,**0**,1,**0**,36...]
```

Overall Output working towards:
Filling the 12x12 matrix where the values would start with:

```
array([28,2,1,4,8,5,1,4,3,3,0,1],[0,36,2,1,0,1,1,2,5,7,2,2],...]
```

```
comm_link_lst = [[(0, 1, 2), (0, 0, 28), (0, 9, 3), (0, 8, 3), (0, 5, 5), (0, 3, 4), (0, 4, 8), (0, 2, 1), (0, 6, 1), (0, 7, 4), (0, 11, 1), (1, 1, 36), (1, 8, 5), (1, 11, 2), (1, 9, 7), (1, 2, 2), (1, 5, 1), (1, 7, 2), (1, 10, 2), (1, 6, 1), (1, 3, 1), (2, 3, 5), (2, 2, 44), (2, 6, 10), (2, 4, 5), (2, 9, 3), (2, 10, 3), (2, 7, 4), (2, 11, 2), (2, 8, 1)...]

num = np.zeros((12,12)) #12 x 12 matrix, faster than filling empty array 

lst2=[]
for i in range(12):
    for j in range(12):
       lst2.append([x[2] for x in comm_link_lst if x[0]==i and x[1]==j])
```

EDIT: Without using the package listed in the solution and directly filling an np.matrix, the answer would be:

```
for i in range(12):
    for j in range(12):
        if [z for x, y, z in comm_link_lst if x==i and y==j] != []:
            num[i][j] = [z for x, y, z in comm_link_lst if x==i and y==j][0]
```

Comment: If your objective is to fill the `num` matrix with values set from the tuples, you could do simple assignments in a loop: `for i,j,n in comm_link_lst: num[i,j] = n`.  Complete input and expected output would help in providing solid answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't understood what's the output you actually want, but this does the matrix thing:

```
from traitlets.traitlets import Undefined
import numpy as np
comm_link_lst = [[(0, 1, 2), (0, 0, 28), (0, 9, 3), (0, 8, 3), (0, 5, 5), (0, 3, 4), (0, 4, 8), (0, 2, 1), (0, 6, 1), (0, 7, 4), (0, 11, 1), (1, 1, 36), (1, 8, 5), (1, 11, 2), (1, 9, 7), (1, 2, 2), (1, 5, 1), (1, 7, 2), (1, 10, 2), (1, 6, 1), (1, 3, 1), (2, 3, 5), (2, 2, 44), (2, 6, 10), (2, 4, 5), (2, 9, 3), (2, 10, 3), (2, 7, 4), (2, 11, 2), (2, 8, 1)]]

num = np.zeros((12,12),dtype=int) #12 x 12 matrix, faster than filling empty array 

for i in range(12):
    for j in range(12):
      if [z for x, y, z in comm_link_lst[0] if x==i and y==j] != []:
        num[i][j] = [z for x, y, z in comm_link_lst[0] if x==i and y==j][0]
lst2=num[0]
print(num)
print("----------------------------------------")
print(lst2)
```

Output:

```
[[28  2  1  4  8  5  1  4  3  3  0  1]
 [ 0 36  2  1  0  1  1  2  5  7  2  2]
 [ 0  0 44  5  5  0 10  4  1  3  3  2]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]]
----------------------------------------
[28  2  1  4  8  5  1  4  3  3  0  1]
```

I hope it helps you

Comment: Thanks, it does!  Can I ask what that that last [0] does at the end of num[i][j] = [z for x, y, z in comm_link_lst[0] if x==i and y==j][0]?

Comment: `[z for x, y, z in comm_link_lst[0] if x==i and y==j]` gives you a list of 1 element, the 0 is to get the element and not the list

Answer (score 0):

Use a conditional expression for the value, rather than conditionalizing the generator.

```
lst2.append([z if x==i and y==j else 0 for x, y, z in comm_link_lst])
```

And you can get the final flat list if you use `lst2.extend()` instead of `lst.append()`.

Comment: This created a different list than the one I listed as the desired output.  However, point taken on tweaking the list comprehension